# I have Tier 2 ICT short term visa granted for 1 month validity

Tags: visas, uk

I have applied for ICT2 short-term visa, requesting it for an 11-month period, but the visa says validity is for 1 month only. If I don't travel within 1 month, can I use it within 11 months?

Comment: So you want to use your visa in 11 months for a month ?

Comment: No, ICT short term Visa is valid for 11 months, but on my passport, it is printed as Visa valid from 28-Sep-2016, Visa expiry 28-Oct-2016. On inquiry i was told that i have to travel within that period to get a validity in UK for 11 months. If i dont travel within this period, can anything be done to travel within 11 months?

Comment: No, it's use or lose.  The question is better situated on Expats where they know more about T2 visas.  Marking for migration to Expats